# Angular - Type '(c: FormControl) => ValidationError | null' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-custom-validators

In Angular-13 I have this code

validation-errors.ts:

```js
import { ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms";
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

// Defines a stronger typed validation error model, compatible with the Angular default.
export interface ValidationError extends ValidationErrors {
    [validatorName: string]: {
        message: string
    }
}
```

validation.component.ts :

```js
import { ValidationError } from '../models/validation-error';

export class CustomValidators {
  static requiredMinNumber(min: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: FormControl): ValidationError | null => {
      if (this.isEmpty(c.value))
        return this.makeError('requiredMinNumber', `You must provide a number of at least ${min}.`);
      else if (!this.isNumber(c.value))
        return this.makeError('requiredMinNumber', `Value must be a number, and minimum ${min}.`);
      else if (c.value < min)
        return this.makeError('requiredMinNumber', `The minimum accepted value is ${min}.`);
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

But this error occurred:

```
Type '(c: FormControl) => ValidationError | null' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
  Types of parameters 'c' and 'control' are incompatible.
    Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'.ts(
```

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write a custom validator, you must follow [`ValidationFn` interface](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn).

```js
interface ValidatorFn {
  (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null
}
```

Change `c` as `AbstractControl` type.

```js
static requiredMinNumber(min: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (c: AbstractControl): ValidationError | null => {
    ...
  };
}
```